# Solr wildcard query on multiple words in text field

Tags: solr, lucene, whitespace, wildcard

I'm searching for "foo" followed by "bar" in a text field named "doc".
My query needs to match the text "foo walks into a bar" but not "bar has place for foo"
I've seen a few similar questions, but no concrete answer.
Queries that don't work:
q=doc:foo*bar
q=doc:/.*foo.*bar.*/
It seems that this is because each word in the text field is tokenized separately. Is there a way to get around this? (Note: I can't change the field type)

Comment: what is the tokenizer you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Surround Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-SurroundQueryParser) and at the [Complex Phrase Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser)

> The SurroundQParser enables the Surround query syntax, which provides
>   proximity search functionality.
>
> There are two positional operators: `w` creates an ordered span query
>   and `n` creates an unordered one. Both operators take a numeric value
>   to indicate distance between two terms. The default is `1`, and the
>   maximum is `99`.
>
> Note that the query string is not analyzed in any way.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> {!surround} 3w(foo, bar)
> ```
>
> This example would find documents where the terms "foo" and "bar" were
>   no more than 3 terms away from each other (i.e., no more than 2 terms
>   between them).

Regarding the Complex Phrase Query Parser, pay attention at the `inOrder` parameter that let you specify the order of the matched keywords.